# How to convert RDD to DStream in JAVA?

Tags: apache-spark

I have checked http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/RDD-to-DStream-td11145.html and want to do the same in JAVA. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per javadoc you can do like this.

```
//Create list
List<SomePojo> somePojoList = ...;             

//Create rdd
JavaRDD<SomePojo> rdd = streamingContext.sparkContext().parallelize( somePojoList);
        java.util.Queue<JavaRDD<SomePojo>> queue = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<SomePojo>>();
        queue.add( rdd );
        JavaDStream<SomePojo> machineDataDstream = streamingContext.queueStream( queue );
```