# queued stream in spark2

Tags: java, apache-spark-2.0

in spark 1.6.1 thank's to this method
[How to convert RDD to DStream in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086708/how-to-convert-rdd-to-dstream-in-java) i was able to create queued stream from text files like this:

```
List<JavaRDD<String>> inputRdds = Arrays.stream(inputDirFile.listFiles((file) -> {
    return file.getName().matches(properties.getInputFileRule());
})).map(file -> {
    return sc().textFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

Queue<JavaRDD<String>> queue = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>(inputRdds);

JavaDStream<String> inputForCheckpointAsStream = jsc().queueStream(queue, true);
```

like this i got stream, but only one file per batch. Files contains JSON data. Is there a way to make queued stream (something like method above) also in spark2 with SparkSession and Datasets without using parquet files?

- `sc()` is java spark context
- `jsc()` is java streaming context